# How to choose the right CNN model for small objects?

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network, image-segmentation, semantic-segmentation

which model would you choose for small object (like rye) segmentation? I have found many state of the art DL models, what would be the best practice while choosing a CNN model for such object?

[image: that's how "small" looks like]

Comment: how do you define "small"? think about "face": it can be HUGE - if you consider selfy images, or tiny - if you consider group photos with dozens of participants...

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory and/or methodology - please see the intro and NOTE in the `machine-learning` [tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info) (applicable also to `deep-learning`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When examining CNN models, one key property you should look at is their [receptive field](https://distill.pub/2019/computing-receptive-fields/): that is the size of the input image region that affects the computed value in the output features.
A large receptive field means each feature is affected by a large image region, "sees" broader context, and can reason about large objects in the image.
On the other hand, a small receptive field means each feature can only "see" a small image region, it is not affected by "context" and is more tuned to observe details in the image.

Therefore, if your goal is to pinpoint small elements in the image, you might consider a CNN that has a small receptive field.

For instance, in *Zamir et al.* "**[Segmenting microcalcifications in mammograms and its applications](https://www.spiedigitallibrary.org/conference-proceedings-of-spie/11596/115962W/Segmenting-microcalcifications-in-mammograms-and-its-applications/10.1117/12.2580398.full?SSO=1)**" (SPIE 2021) the goal is to localize tiny residues in breast mammograms and therefore the authors opted to use a CNN with a particularly small receptive field.
They also showed that using "classical" CNNs with larger receptive fields hurt performance for this specific task.